# How to make a list of sfml sprites and use a for loop to make them "solid"

Tags: c++

I have a house sprite and a character sprite. I do not want my character to "go through" the house sprite and all future house sprites. So how do I add the house sprite to a list and then make it so that for every house in house_sprites, character sprite cannot pass through? Or if there is any other way to make my character not "go through" multiple sprites without programming the collisions for them 1 by 1. I am using c++ and sfml with xcode. I dont want to write the following code for every "solid" sprite in the game. So how do I make it so that I can add a sprite to a list if I want it to be "solid"?
`

```
   if(sprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects(EnterHouse.getGlobalBounds()))
    {

        if (GoingLeft == true)
        {
            x_pos = x_pos + speed;
            x = x + speed;
        }
        if(GoingDown == true)
        {
            y_pos = y_pos - speed;
            y = y - speed;
        }
        if(GoingRight == true)
        {

            x_pos = x_pos - speed;
            x = x - speed;
        }
        if(GoingUp == true and y > 2530)
        {
            y_pos = y_pos + speed;
            y = y + speed;
        }
        if(GoingUp == true and x_pos < 20230)
        {
            x_pos = x_pos - speed;
            x = x - speed;
        }
        if(GoingUp == true and x_pos > 20230)
        {
            x_pos = x_pos + speed;
            x = x + speed;
        }
        if(GoingDown == true and x_pos < 20230)
        {
            x_pos = x_pos - speed;
            x = x - speed;
        }
        if(GoingDown == true and x_pos > 20230)
        {
            x_pos = x_pos + speed;
            x = x + speed;
        }`
```

Comment: Your question had nothing to do with adding-to-a-list. That was your assumption regarding the solution. Please try to keep the tiltle focused on the actual problem. I know it's not an easy thing, especially when you have your thoughts elsewhere, but really - after you wrote the question, if you'd go back and spend a moment on rethinking the title, you'd probably notice that `my character not "go through" multiple sprites` was the core, not "add to a list" :)

Comment: If you think my answer clarified you, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

SFML doesnt handle collisions automagically, it is a Simple and Fast Multimedia Library. You will have to implement collisions yourself or use another library such as Box2D.

Answer (score 0):

Well considering your edit, you could do the following:
Have 4 bools, one for each direction: `canGoUp`, `canGoDown`, `canGoLeft` and `canGoRight`.

Set them to false by default.
Now make a loop where you iterate over a list of the sprites you want to check the collisions, and do your collision check: (pseudo c++)

```
for (every collidableSprite)
if(sprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects(collidableSprite.getGlobalBounds())) {
 (...) // Set the direction bools to true or false, depending on the direction of the house relative to the sprite
}
```

Afterwards, you just need to make the sprite move, something along the lines of this:

```
if (wantsToGoLeft && canGoLeft) {
 // Move sprite to the left
}
else if (...)
```

There you go. Now if you want to add another house you need to it to the list you iterate on step 1.

Comment: ya but how do I make that list?

Comment: How do you make that list? You can have a `std::list` of sprites, and then use `push_back` to add sprites or `remove` to remove one.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot figure out how to iterate over a list of sprites with a for loop. My list looks like: std::list<sf::Sprite> solids {};                                             I am pretty new to c++

Comment: You should really check a C++ tutorial on `std::list` and other containers.